# Print values in customized train_step function using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Following this guide https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/ I have created a custom version of the train_step that will be called when calling model.fit()

```
    @tf.function
    def train_step(self, x, y):
        ''' Adapted from https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/ '''
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            logits = model(x, training=True)
            trainable_vars = model.trainable_variables
            loss = custom_loss(y, logits)
            
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, logits)
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
```

when I then fit the model as

```
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=custom_loss)
model.fit(x,y)
```

the model is trained, however when I try to print something inside the train_step() function I see no output, making me wonder if .fit() actually calls my customized function? Or is what I'm trying to print being printed somewhere in the backend that I cant see in the console?

Answer (score 1):

you should better use `tf.print("...")` inside train_step during training. I suggest to keep the original tensorflow fit method by replacing it with `callback` one, then you have multiple options allow you to run your code during training or at the end of epoch or validation.

Example of creating customized callback which print date after the beginning and the end of each epoch:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from datetime import datetime

class date_callback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def __init__(self):
   super(date_callback, self).__init__()
   #other inits if necessary
  
  def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs = None):
   now = datetime.now()
   tf.print("epoch begin at", now)

  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs = None):
   now = datetime.now()
   tf.print("epoch end at", now)

...
...
#running the model training

dc = date_callback()
model.fit(..., callbacks = [dc])
```